# Null value while decrypting column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure and by this I have inserted value through encryption. But when I try to decrypt that value it is not decrypted properly. Please help what I have to do when inserting the encrypted value though procedure.

The code is:

```
create TABLE customer(
customer_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT pk_cust_id PRIMARY KEY,
salary varbinary(300)
)

create symmetric key sk_customer with algorithm = aes_192 encryption by password = 'abc@1234';
open symmetric key sk_customer decryption by password = 'abc@1234';

INSERT INTO customer(salary) VALUES(encryptbykey(key_guid('sk_customer'),'123.001254', 1, '1'))

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertCustomer]
(
@salary varbinary(300)
)
as
begin
open symmetric key sk_customer decryption by password = 'abc@1234';

INSERT INTO customer(salary)VALUES (
encryptbykey(key_guid('sk_customer '),@salary,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@@IDENTITY))
)
SELECT @@IDENTITY
close symmetric key sk_customer;   
end
GO

EXEC usp_InsertCustomer
        @salary = 852.369
SELECT customer_id,convert(varchar(max),decryptbykey(salary,1, convert(varchar(10),customer_id))) as 'Salary' FROM customer
```

Comment: Don't you have to use customer_id, not @@identity in encryption params?

Comment: I have tried that also

Comment: Also tried? Do you at least understand, what every parameter to en/decryption functions means? Or what @@identity does? Play initailly with fixed values and variables; when you have encryption-decryption code working with known data, then you can more easily usa that with real tables and data.

Comment: Well, I didn't pay enough attention to your table structure - you don't know customer_id beforehand. Can you encrypt-decrypt without using authenticator (or using some constant value for it)?